# From subquery to join. How do I join three tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, **Property**, **Address** and **City**.

```
******************************
| Property | Address | City |
******************************
| Property_id | address_id | city_id |
**************************************
| address_id (fk)  |    city_id (fk)   |    city_name  |
```

I've used a subquery to select the address_id corresponding to properties in London using the following SQL script:

```
SELECT * FROM Property WHERE address_id IN (
    SELECT address_id FROM Address WHERE city_id = (
        SELECT city_id FROM City WHERE city_name = 'London'));
```

I'd like to use a join to do this, but I'm not sure how this is done with three tables. Can I get some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JOIN` is simpler . . . no so many subqueries:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM Property p JOIN
     Address a
     ON p.address_id = a.address_id JOIN
     City c
     ON a.city_id = c.city_id
WHERE c.city_name = 'London';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two methods:
1. using inner join

`Select *
from
property a 
inner join
address b on a.address_id=b.address_id
inner join 
city c on b.city_id=c.city_id
where c.city_name = 'London';`

2. by specifying where condition:(If you don't want to use inner join)

`Select *
from
property a,address b,city c
where a.address_id=b.address_id 
and b.city_id=c.city_id
and c.city_name = 'London';`